# Inno Setup - Do not install DirectX when already installed

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using this code in `[Run]` section:

```
Filename: "{src}\DirectX\DXSETUP.exe"; StatusMsg: "Wait for install DirectX package..."; \
  Flags: waituntilterminated skipifsilent skipifdoesntexist
```

And when I try to reinstall program, every time I get pop-up with DirectX installation. How to prevent reinstalling DirectX, when it's installed already?

Answer (score 2):

See ISXKB for [DirectX - How to detect DirectX version](https://web.archive.org/web/20130329233431/http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=DirectX_-_How_to_detect_DirectX_version) article.

It has useful functions, which you can use to detect, if required version of DirectX is already installed on the machine.

Using these functions, you can easily implement a [check function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck):

```
[Run]
Filename: "{src}\DirectX\DXSETUP.exe"; 
  StatusMsg: "Wait for install DirectX package..."; \
  Flags: waituntilterminated skipifsilent skipifdoesntexist; Check: InstallDirectX
```

```pascal
[Code]

function InstallDirectX: Boolean;
begin
  Result := (CompareVersion(GetDirectXVersion(), '4.8.0') < 0);
end;
```